# Python: Calling a class based on variable's value

Tags: python, class

Essentially what I want this code to do, is replace `(systemType).clear()` with either `unix.clear` or `windows.clear`. Is this even possible?

```
if(platform.system()=="Windows"):
    systemType="windows"
else:
    systemType="unix"

class unix:
    def clear():
        os.system('clear')

class windows:
    def clear():
        os.system('cls')


print("Detecing systemType")
time.sleep(1)
(systemType).clear()
```

The error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'clear'`

Comment: os.system('cls') if 'windows' in platform.system().lower() else os.system('clear')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you move the assignment of `systemType` to after the class definitions, you can assign it the classes themselves rather than their names:

```
class unix:
    def clear():
        os.system('clear')

class windows:
    def clear():
        os.system('cls')

if platform.system()=="Windows":
    systemType = windows
else:
    systemType = unix

print("Detecing systemType")
time.sleep(1)
systemType.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
if os.name == "nt":
     os.system("cls") #windows
else:
     os.system("clear") #unix
```

Comment: This works, however I wanted an easy way to add functions to execute based on the operating system. Not just a cluster of if statements in one function.